# Processing for Android 3, registerReceiver and getApplicationContext functions do not exist

Tags: android, function, compiler-errors, processing

I'm busy trying to piece together an app to transfer some data between an Android device and an Arduino.

The original code is taken from a tutorial and was written for Processing 2.0b, developing for API 10.

I am using Processing 3, developing for API 15.

This is the code:

```
/* DiscoverBluetooth: Written by ScottC on 18 March 2013 using 
 Processing version 2.0b8
 Tested on a Samsung Galaxy SII, with Android version 2.3.4
 Android ADK - API 10 SDK platform */

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;



boolean foundDevice=false; //When this is true, the screen turns green.

//Get the default Bluetooth adapter
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


/*The startActivityForResult() within setup() launches an 
 Activity which is used to request the user to turn Bluetooth on. 
 The following onActivityResult() method is called when this 
 Activity exits. */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
 if(requestCode==0){
 if(resultCode == -1){
 ToastMaster("Bluetooth has been switched ON");
 } else {
 ToastMaster("You need to turn Bluetooth ON !!!");
 }
 }
}



/* Create a Broadcast Receiver that will later be used to 
 receive the names of Bluetooth devices in range. */
BroadcastReceiver myDiscoverer = new myOwnBroadcastReceiver();



void setup(){
 orientation(LANDSCAPE);
 /*IF Bluetooth is NOT enabled, then ask user permission to enable it */
 if (!bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
 Intent requestBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
 startActivityForResult(requestBluetooth, 0);
 }

 /*If Bluetooth is now enabled, then register a broadcastReceiver to report any
 discovered Bluetooth devices, and then start discovering */
 if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
 registerReceiver(myDiscoverer, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
 //Start bluetooth discovery if it is not doing so already
 if (!bluetooth.isDiscovering()){
 bluetooth.startDiscovery();
 }
 }
}



void draw(){
 //Display a green screen if a device has been found
 if(foundDevice){
 background(10,255,10);
 }
}



/* This BroadcastReceiver will display discovered Bluetooth devices */
public class myOwnBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 String discoveredDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);

 //Display the name of the discovered device
 ToastMaster("Discovered: " + discoveredDeviceName);

 //Change foundDevice to true which will make the screen turn green
 foundDevice=true;
 }
}

/* My ToastMaster function to display a messageBox on the screen */

void ToastMaster(String textToDisplay){
 Toast myMessage = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
 textToDisplay,
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 myMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
 myMessage.show();
}
```

I'm getting compile errors on lines 57 and 93 stating:

```
The function "registerRevceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)" does not exist
The function "getApplicationContext()" does not exist
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to get this code example to work? I suspect it's an issue to do with the API level and some library mismatching of sorts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Jono

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getApplicationContext()` use `ActivityName.this`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I gave that a try, but I get another compiler error: "The class "ActivityName" does not exist". Is there something that I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: I meant put the name of the class for your activity there. MainActivity or whatever it's called.

Comment: I'm not sure what it's called. Could you have a look at the code and tell me where to find it? That would be helpful. Also, why can I not use getApplicationContext()?

Comment: I only now realised this isn't an Android app, sorry. Still, try to use just `this`.

Comment: No worries. I tried that, it then gives the error `The function "makeText()" expects parameters like: "makeText(Context, CharSequence,int)"`. Thanks for your help in any case.